# How to toggle a `<textarea>`’s `spellcheck` attribute with a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I’d like to have a checkbox that, when checked, will enable a `<textarea>`’s `spellcheck` attribute and vice-versa.

However, I’m not sure if this is possible.

This is my code so far:

```js
document.getElementById('sampleCheckbox').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let textArea = document.getElementById('sampleTextarea');
  
  textArea.setAttribute('spellcheck', 'true') = !textArea.setAttribute('spellcheck', 'false')
});
```

```html
Enable/Disable Spellcheck <input type="checkbox" id="sampleCheckbox" checked>
<br>
<br>
<textarea spellcheck="true" rows="5" cols="50" id="sampleTextarea">sadadadadadsasamkdajdakmkmxzcm</textarea>
```

How do I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax wouldn’t work because you can’t assign to the result of a function.

The [`spellcheck`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck) attribute has the somewhat weird requirement that its values should match exactly `"true"` or `"false"`.
This means it’s an enumerated attribute, but not a boolean attribute.
But the values *are* boolean literals, as strings.

If you encounter any attribute that behaves this way, this is how you can toggle it:

```js
textArea.setAttribute("spellcheck", !JSON.parse(textArea.getAttribute("spellcheck")));
```

[`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) accepts (among other things) a boolean literal as a string, i.e. `"true"` or `"false"`, and turns it into an actual boolean.
The string value is retrieved with [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).
The [logical NOT (`!`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT) inverts the parsed boolean.
Then, [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) sets the result (no need to convert the boolean back into a string: attribute values can only be strings, so `setAttribute` performs this conversion for you).

*If* you had a true boolean attribute such as `contenteditable`, then this is much easier done with [`toggleAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/toggleAttribute).

Your event listener relies on the `click` event.
But toggling a checkbox can be achieved many other ways (e.g. keyboard navigation, touch, etc.).
Use the `change` event instead.

```js
document.getElementById("sampleCheckbox").addEventListener("change", () => {
  const textArea = document.getElementById("sampleTextarea");
  
  textArea.setAttribute("spellcheck", !JSON.parse(textArea.getAttribute("spellcheck")));
});
```

```html
<label>Enable / Disable Spellcheck: <input id="sampleCheckbox" type="checkbox" checked></label>

<textarea id="sampleTextarea" spellcheck="true" rows="5" cols="50">sadadadadadsasamkdajdakmkmxzcm</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event listener to the `change` event on the checkbox element and then use `setAttribute` to set the `spellcheck` to the value of the checkbox.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    document.querySelector('textarea').setAttribute('spellcheck', e.currentTarget.checked)
})
```

```html
<textarea spellcheck="true">This is a spellling mistake.</textarea>
<label><input type="checkbox" checked>Spellcheck?</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

- To handle checkbox events use `change` instead of `click`.
- Use an argument inside `function(e)` to access the event. You can use any argument instead of `e`.
- Use `e.target.checked` which will return `true` if checked and `false` if not.
- Then perform any action

```js
let checkBox = document.getElementById('sampleCheckbox');
     checkBox.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      let textArea = document.getElementById('sampleTextarea');
      if (e.target.checked) {
        textArea.setAttribute('spellcheck', 'true')
      }else{
        textArea.setAttribute('spellcheck', 'false')
      }
});
```

```html
Enable/Disable Spellcheck <input type="checkbox" id="sampleCheckbox" checked> <br><br>

<textarea spellcheck="true" rows="5" cols="50" id="sampleTextarea">sadadadadadsasamkdajdakmkmxzcm</textarea>
```